# Load scripts after AJAX loads content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I'm using `jQuery` and `YQL` to get the content of a website and display a certain element on the page, in this case, the `table` element. I also have a search function set up using the [jQuery QuickSearch](http://lomalogue.com/jquery/quicksearch/) plugin.

*This works great, and now to the problem...*

It seems that the search script is loading before the `AJAX` content getter gets the content. I think the script then caches the data, so that it's easier to search. Since it's loading after the content is there though, it doesn't search anything and it doesn't work. Is there any way to load the search script **AFTER** the `AJAX` content is loaded?

I already attempted calling it via the `ready` function in jQ:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

But that still loads before the content is loaded. My `AJAX` script is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var container = $('#content');
        function doAjax(url) {
            if (url.match('^http')) {
                $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
                    "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
                    encodeURIComponent(url)+
                    "%22&format=xml'&callback=?", 
                function (data) {
                    if (data.results[0]) {
                        var fullResponse = $(filterData(data.results[0])),
                            justTable = fullResponse.find("table");
                        container.append(justTable);
                    } else {
                        var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
                        container.html(errormsg);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#content').load(url);
            }
        }
        function filterData(data) {
            data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g, '');
            data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g, '');
            data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g, '');
            data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g, '');
            data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g, '');
            data = data.replace(/<script.*\/>/, '');
            data = data.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, '');
            return data;
        }
        doAjax('url_goes_here');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 14):

Not sure I really get the question, but to load a script after the content is loaded with Ajax you could do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function() {
     //success loading content
  },
  error: function() {
    //error loading content
  },
  complete: function() {
     $.getScript("/scripts/mysearchscript.js", function() {
          alert('loaded script and content');
     });
  }
});
```

Comment: What part don't you get? I want to refine the answer to be more clear :D

Comment: Also, to add onto this.. I'm not getting the content from a local page. This passes a url to YQL, and then gets the page's content sent back and stripped of everything but `table` tags. I'm not sure what the syntax would like like since it's just an `ajax` request, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

"If .ready() is called after the DOM has been initialized, the new handler passed in will be executed immediately." - http://api.jquery.com/ready/

**EDIT**

I think I may have misinterpreted your question, sorry.  Are you saying that the search tries to search before the table is fully loaded?  I thought you were trying to search before the page had completed loading.  Have you tried using a callback function attached to your .load(), or just after container.append()?

after load

```
$('#content').load(url,callSearchFunction());
```

you can do it much simpler after append

```
 container.append(justTable);
 callSearchFunction();
```

Comment: I'm trying to interpret what that means. I should be calling the `.ready()` first, then the AJAX, and then the search will load once the AJAX loads?

Comment: It means if you are calling the .ready() function in a script inside the body then it runs instantly and should be run from the head.

Comment: Both the scripts are in the head though.

Comment: Yes, I am wanting the search script to load after the page's content has loaded from the AJAX request. How would I go about using a callback?

Comment: So I'd have to rewrite the code to get the content? Is there a jQuery function for after AJAX has loaded?

Comment: Once the data has been retrieved in function(data) then the AJAX has loaded and you can call your script function.  Also, the second parameted of $.load(first,second) is the callback function which will be called after the ajax is loaded.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm kind of understanding it. Once the content is loaded into `data`, which would be done when the content is loaded, then call the search script?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good time to call it, right after the data that is loaded is appended.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6595/discussion-between-charlie-and-travis-j)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container').load('yourPage.html',function(){          
    //Do whatever you want here              
});
```

You can pass an anonymous function like a parameter on the jquery method .load()

http://api.jquery.com/load/

That function will execute when the ajax request is complete